# How to trigger event when Formatted Field automatically changes invalid input - (Swing) Java

Tags: java, swing, events, triggers

I'm trying to obtain a valid Date as input, with format dd/mm/yy and I do want the Formatted Field to automatically change the value when the input is something along the lines of 01/12/1992 or -4/12/-16. Until here it's all already done and ok.

But is there any way, in which I can trigger an event (e.g. a pop-up window) when the Formatted Field does this conversion?

Thanks.

edit: If someone sees this, I didn't find a solution and finally decided I don't care enough to solve it.

Comment: So trigger it after doing that conversion. Is not it working?

Comment: My problem is that it makes that conversion automatically when the field loses focus if the input is not in the correct format. But how can I check if the input has been automatically changed?

Comment: I see, you are using a third party component which code is not avaliable for edit, right?